# restore default css attributes

Tags: html, css

i'm writing a component that is to be used across multiple websites.

each website has it's own stylesheets and displays certain things differently.

all of my html is wrapped within a div with an id:

```
<div id="myComponent">...</div>
```

my component however is to look consistent across all of the sites.

this is fine as i apply styling to most of the attributes in my component.

```
div#myComponent p {font-size:11px;} etc
```

however i've come across a site that removes the border from all input fields

```
input {border: medium none;}
```

i need to 'un-apply' this directive for the input fields within my component, and preferrably use the browser's default styling for inputs, as the border style for `input type="text"` will need be different to `input type="button"`.

how would you achieve this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99643/css-reset-default-styles-for-common-elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to redefine it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Common_CSS_Questions#Restoring_the_default_property_value

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert

Answer (score 5):

You can do it now since CSS2: `border:initial;`

Answer (score 2):

```
div#myComponent input { border: 1px inset; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use styles for different input types/

css :

```
div#myComponent input[type=text] { border:dashed 1px #ccc;} 
div#myComponent input[type=button] { border:solid 1px #999;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to add a class to the input.
Here is a jquery example...

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#myComponent input[type=text]").addClass("borderMe");
    }); 
</script>
```

and then define 'borderMe' in a stylesheet (or style tag)

```
<style type = "text/css">
.borderMe
{
    border:solid 2px black;
}
</style>
```