# Style heading tags with css reset

Tags: css, html, css-reset, html-heading

After using a css reset, all my heading tags are reset (ofcourse). What is the best way to style them like normal.

Surely there is better way then this?

```
h1 { font-size: 2em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.5em; }
h3 { font-size: 1.3em; }
h4 { font-size: 1em; }
h5 { font-size: 0.8em; }
h6 { font-size: 0.7em; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Reset, default styles for common elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99643/css-reset-default-styles-for-common-elements)

Comment: You mean the css reset has something like `* {font-size:1em}`? Things like that don't actually solve any problems, you know. To answer your question: yes, there is a better way. Don't use the css reset. But if you absolutely must, then what you have there in your question is not enough; you'll also need to restore the font-weight and the top and bottom margins for each of the headers.

Comment: It didn't answer my question but it did lead me to normalize.css which eliminates the problem altogether. \o/

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 6):

The way that you have set up the new header style will work fine. You might want think about adding

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

to make sure the type is default set to non italic/oblique or bold (unless you want the default to be strong)